# Deploying Django app on pythonanywhere.com

Tags: mysql, django

I am facing issues during migration with MySql database during my Django app deployment on PythonAnywhere.com. Following is the error:

django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1170, "BLOB/TEXT column 'examname' used in key specification without a key length")

'examname' is not a primary key in my model. But, I still get the error.

Here is my model:

```
class ExamName(models.Model):
     examname = models.TextField(unique=True)
     total_questions = models.IntegerField()
     duration = models.IntegerField()
     start_time = models.DateTimeField()                                                                                                                           
     end_time = models.DateTimeField()
     mark_per_qtn = models.IntegerField()
```

Comment: Show your model code.

Comment: @User42 Added my model

Comment: You can not keep unique=True on mysql columns with column length more than 255.
Define the examname as varchar and provide maxlength less than 255. Then it will work.

Comment: I changed the examname to `examname = models.CharField(max_length=150)`. But I get the same error

Comment: examname = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True) should work fine.

Comment: Are you sure the error is *exactly* the same?  It would be weird if it complained about a BLOB/TEXT column if you'd made it a CharField.   Perhaps you didn't delete the old migration before generating the new one?  Then it would try to migrate the table to using a TextField first, then to a CharField second, so you'd get the same error on the first of those.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Deleting the old migrations and doing the migration again worked.